# CSS размер текста относительно чего?

Tags: html, css

Если написать так, то размер текста будет 150% от его стандартного размера или 150% от размера блока в котором он находится?

```css
p {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За 100% берется размер шрифта родительского элемента.

[Источник](http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-size).

А [здесь](https://htmlacademy.ru/courses/43/run/2) можете поиграться.